# How do i remove the white spaces from my html website?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding how to remove the white space on the right side of the page. The width of body was set to 1903 as a default but I changed it to 1600 and now I just the image to be fit to the right side, it should be covering the white spaces, or, It would be better if I could just remove those white spaces, help would be appreciated

Comment: WIthout seeing the code, nobody can provide help

Comment: it would be helpful to review if you shared the code or link to your site

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out which element cause this issue to happen first.

Click the right button of the mouse to open **Inspector**, you will see the devtool.

Take StackOverflow as an example, when I move the mouse to the right side area, you can refer to the right side black control panel to see the specific element of HTML, below it, is its style.

You can type legal CSS into **element.style** block to see the changes immediately.

[image]

Back to your case, to cause this issue have many reasons:

1. The diagram has no enough width and height, if it is a background, you can fix it with this:

```
.img{
  background: url(...);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover ( or background-size: 100% 100% )
}
```

2. The parent container has some padding:

```
.parent{
  padding: 0
}
```

3. The image container has some margin:

```
.img-container {
  margin: 0
}
```

It has too many reasons to come out this result, **the point of it is to find out which element causes this.**

You can provide an online demo, then we can just see what's going on directly, either we just can guess the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that whatever rules you write in css are implemented on any resolution the device that runs the page. I would guess you are running at a 1080x1980 screen. which means that 1980-1600=380px.That is the number of pixels you have extra that you need to take into consideration.If you render that in a monitor that has greater resolution you would have even more white spaces, and if you render that into a mobile device you would exceed the size of the screen and you would need to scroll to see the whole of it. Thats something you can read about when studying about responsive css and resolutions as a whole but for starters you can remove the bodys width and try:

```
img {width:100vw;}
```

Which means
100vw = 100 view width = 100% of the screens available width, which in your case would remove the white space and stretch the image fully to fill the resolution you're running.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it